# Create REST Service for Grades in Peoplesoft

Tags: rest, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I have a grade service (CI_ENRL_GRADES). I need to make a REST Service of that existing service. How can I do it? please assist me with appropriate steps or any information would be much appreciated. THANKS !!!

Comment: what version of PeopleTools? What version of Campus Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a message + service operation + service to support your rest. You will need to define a JSON on the message so you can share it with the legacy system that will send you information.
Make sure you have the rest listening connector setup, and has provided the operation after finished.